# Finding the biggest number in a file (containing both numeric and non numeric elements) with Perl

Tags: perl, search

I really need the help of a Perl hacker. This looks easy but I have been thinking about it for an hour and didnt come with any solution.

Assuming we have a flat or log file like the following.:

```
    2013-05-27T19:01:23 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:29 [INFO] item_id:2, pause at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:1, start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:3, start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:3, start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:3, start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
    2013-05-27T19:01:30 [INFO] item_id:5, start at Reader.pm line 23
    (...)
```

I have to make a method that finds the biggest item_id number, in this case 5 and locate it in a variable $found. Notice that we do not know a priori which is the largest number, so I cannot use grep because i would need to put the "biggest number (that is, 5 in this case)" as an input. The only input we have is the location of the file. What do you suggest?

Comment: For information, the perl one liners and loops are the fastest at about 600ms.  Looped programs are 700-800ms.  `max @ids` is about 900ms.  `cut | sed | sort` is 1200ms.  `sed | sort` is the slowest by far at 3800ms.

Comment: @Schwern Thanks for the info. By the way, how would you test a task like this one?

Comment: `use File::Temp; use Test::More; my $tmp = File::Temp->new; print $tmp $test_log_data; is max_item_id_in_log($tmp->filename), $expected_max_item_id; done_testing;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[List::Util](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aUtil) has a max() function which will select the largest number.

```
use List::Util qw(max);

my @ids;
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    my($id) = $line =~ /item_id:(\d+)/;
    push @ids, $id;
}

print max(@ids);
```

For edification, max is a pretty straight forward function to implement.

```
sub max {
    my $max;
    for my $num (@_) {
        $max = $num if $num > $max;
    }

    return $max;
}
```

If you have a tremendous number of lines you can do the max calculation in the loop to avoid having to store a list.

```
my $max;
while(my $line = <$fh>) {
    my($id) = $line =~ /item_id:(\d+)/;
    $max = $id if $id > $max;
}
```

Comment: @Schwern Thanks I like this one. The file has half a million lines so I was looking for something neat.

Comment: @squiguy I was wondering that myself. Using an array is a bit wasteful, but even at half a million lines it doesn't make a dent in performance or memory. An array of half a million integers is just 4 megs. `max` can tear through them in milliseconds. All the cost will be in reading the file.

Comment: The "tremendous number of lines" solution seems more straightforward than the `List::Util` solution; I'd prefer it even for small inputs.

Comment: @squidguy, Q: how do I multiply two numbers?  Analogue of this answer: here's a peano number module that supports multiplication.  Factorial 5 consumes 100MB of RAM and takes ten minutes to run to completion on my system, so if you're dealing with crazy large numbers you might want to *grudgingly do the obviously preferable thing*.

Comment: @JulianFondren Let's keep our heads. The `max` solution costs 900ms, the while loop costs 700ms. I/O and parsing is the majority of the cost. I showed two solutions. Doing the math in the loop is the fastest and most memory efficient, and taking the max of a list is most natural if the log data is going to be parsed and stored for other purposes.

Comment: @Schwern, OK, you can underline 'grudgingly' in my comment as many times as you want, but you're still building an array to maintain a scalar's worth of information.

Answer (score 4):

This solution is very straightforward. It expects the name of the input file as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $found = 0;

while (<>) {
  next unless /item_id:(\d+)/;
  $found = $1 if $found < $1;
}

print "Found: $found";
```

**output**

```
Found: 5
```

---

**Update**

If all you want is the value then there is this command-line version

```
perl -ne "/item_id:(\d+)/ && $f<$1 and $f=$1; END{print $f}" data.txt
```

Comment: @squiguy: Did you give it a file name parameter like I said?

Comment: I didn't down vote, I know it takes a file name for the command line.

Comment: Probably cause you said you got `0` for output when the OP requested it give `5`??? Fixed that issue if that's the case.

Comment: @squiguy, You can also provide input via STDIN

Comment: I thought the solution looked correct, so I just wanted to point that out so people would up vote. +1

Comment: Using `and` instead of `if` is longer and more confusing. It's also needs a `-l` cause it's missing a terminal newline. Wouldn't call that amazing.

Comment: Golfed: `perl -nE'$f=$1 if/item_id:(\d+)/&&$f<$1}{say$f'`

Answer (score 3):

Just read in every line of the log file and use regex to pick up the game ids, initialize the game id with the first one, and replace it when you get a larger id.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $location = "file.txt";
open LOGFILE, $location;

my $first_line = 1;
my $max_id;

while (<LOGFILE>) {
    if (/item_id:(\d)+/) {
        if ($first_line) {
            $first_line = 0;
            $max_id = $1;
        } else {
            $max_id = $1 if ($1 > $max_id);
        }
    }
}

my $found = $max_id;
print "$found\n";

close LOGFILE;
```

Comment: Yep. As a one-liner, and assuming that the IDs are never all negative: `perl -lne '$id = $1 if /item_id:(\d+)/ and $1 > $id; END { print $id }' thefile`

Comment: If you want to check for the first line of input then use `$. == 1`

Answer (score 2):

As a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne '{$s{$1}++ if /item_id:(\d+)/} END{print ((sort keys %s)[-1])}' input
```

or,

```
perl -nle '{$m = $1 if /item_id:(\d+)/ and $1 > $m} END{print $m}' input
```

Because you mentioned grep, here is a way to do this using command line tools:

```
cut -d' ' -f3 input | sed 's/[^:]*:\([0-9]*\),/\1/' | sort -nr | head -1
```

or,

```
sed 's/.*item_id:\([0-9]*\),.*/\1/' input | sort -nr | head -1
```

Comment: This is a question about *Perl*

Comment: why not do the cut in sed?  or the number extraction with cut (e.g. `cut -d, -f1 input | cut -d: -f4 | sort ...`

Comment: @Borodin: `$found = qx'sed...'` :)

Comment: @Borodin, thanks for some reason I thought OP referred to `grep` as in the command line tool